# Anime series where a spaceship had to travel after receiving an advanced power source from an alien race to save humanity

Tags: story-identification, anime

I don't remember the exact year or even month that I saw this anime series, but I was a small boy, around 5 or 6, so it had to be around 39 or 40 years ago that it was out in South Africa. No idea what that means in the context of the whole world though, since we got series at different times.

All I can remember about it was that a spaceship and crew had to travel one light year from earth and then back again, after receiving an advanced power source from an alien race, in order to save humanity. I remember the crew having a last chance to talk to loved one's back to Earth before leaving the solar system. One older male crew member said something like, "..she doesn't have radiation sickness, does she?..", (regarding his granddaughter) whilst a younger man said," ... I don't have anyone (left) to talk to on Earth.."

It's a nostalgia thing and, whilst I couldn't really properly reward anyone able to help me track this series down, it would mean a great deal to me to find it again after all this time.

Comment: @BrianTosio, what month did you last see this show?

Comment: I don't remember the exact year or even month that I saw this anime series, but I was a small boy, around 5 or 6, so it had to be around 39 or 40 years ago that it was out in South Africa. No idea what that means in  the context of the whole world though, since we got series at different times. Wish I could give more info.

Comment: This sounds like it could be some sort of Leijiverse story (*Space Pirate Harlock*, *Battleship Yamato*, *Galaxy Express 999*).

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like [Space Battleship Yamato](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0140644/) also released under the names *Space Cruiser Yamato* and *Cosmoship Yamato* worldwide and as *Star Blazers* in the USA.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Battleship_Yamato):

> In the year 2199, an alien race known as Gamilas (Gamilons in the English Star Blazers dub) unleash radioactive meteorite bombs on Earth, rendering the planet's surface uninhabitable. Humanity has retreated into deep underground cities, but the radioactivity is slowly affecting them as well, with humanity's extinction estimated in one year. Earth has a space fleet, but they do not yet have interstellar capability, and they are hopelessly outclassed by Gamilas. All seems lost until a message capsule from a mysterious crashed spaceship is retrieved on Mars. The capsule yields blueprints for a faster-than-light engine and an offering of help from Queen Starsha of the planet Iscandar in the Large Magellanic Cloud. She says that her planet has a device, the Cosmo-Cleaner D (Cosmo DNA), which can cleanse Earth of its radiation damage.

Comment: Huh... so I was on the right track. :) The Leijiverse kept popping up on searches, but I couldn't find anything definitive.

Comment: Thanks so much for that Legion600, you've made my day. Certainly sounds like what I vaguely remember from 40 years ago. I shall look it up now. :)

Comment: And thanks too to F1Krazy, you did actually suggest that as a possibility further up, I just realised now, but I haven't watched enough Anime and didn't recognise any of the names. After searching for years I'm amazed to actually have received any responses, let alone the exact info I was looking for. Thanks so much to the community for the assistance. One nostalgic trip down memory lane coming up.